# Access Denied on Ghost s3 storage with region:null

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ghost

I'm trying to set up a Ghost blog using [ghost-s3-storage](https://github.com/muzix/ghost-s3). I've done this before without issues but can't seem to get it this time. I don't think it's the bucket permissions. Is the region:null below a clue?

Here's the error I'm getting on upload:

```
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881035+00:00 app[web.1]: error in ghost-s3 { [AccessDenied: Access Denied]
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881077+00:00 app[web.1]: message: 'Access Denied',
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881081+00:00 app[web.1]: time: Wed Jun 08 2016 15:42:06 GMT+0000 (UTC),
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881079+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'AccessDenied',
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881080+00:00 app[web.1]: region: null,
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881083+00:00 app[web.1]: extendedRequestId: '9pm89M2uPOWf2bhXIYjZ0osMsX+fuBAMszuaZIx/oUVA/wSDVDO3d07lSfbEXuqnQe6xohwDDg8=',
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881084+00:00 app[web.1]: cfId: undefined,
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881085+00:00 app[web.1]: statusCode: 403,
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881085+00:00 app[web.1]: retryable: false,
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881086+00:00 app[web.1]: retryDelay: 49.723599618300796 }
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886449+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886465+00:00 app[web.1]: AccessDenied: Access Denied
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886468+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886466+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.extractError (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:473:35)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886463+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: Access Denied
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886464+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-08T15:42:06.881082+00:00 app[web.1]: requestId: '81D1EEB75F964D1C',
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886468+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886469+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.transition (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886471+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886470+00:00 app[web.1]: at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886472+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886473+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886476+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886474+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.emit (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886475+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.transition (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886475+00:00 app[web.1]: at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886477+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886478+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886479+00:00 app[web.1]: at callNextListener (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886473+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886478+00:00 app[web.1]: at Request. (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886482+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886480+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/ghost-s3-storage/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:209:11)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886481+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886481+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.887561+00:00 app[web.1]: 24.130.248.207 - - [08/Jun/2016:15:42:06 +0000] "POST /ghost/api/v0.1/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 403 74 "https://secure-retreat-26998.herokuapp.com/ghost/editor/1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886483+00:00 app[web.1]: at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886483+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)
2016-06-08T15:42:06.886484+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-08T15:42:06.869275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/ghost/api/v0.1/uploads/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=e99bb332-dc4f-40f4-943d-918c0d870df8 fwd="24.130.248.207" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=786ms status=403 bytes=407
```

Here is my config.js:

```
    storage: {
      active: 'ghost-s3',
      'ghost-s3': {
          accessKeyId: 'ID',
          secretAccessKey: 'secret',
          bucket: 'bucketname',
          region: 'us-west-1',
          assetHost: 'https://bucketname.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' 
      }
    }
```

The region is clearly there, so why is it null in the logs?

Comment: I don't think `region: null` is actually meaningful, here.  I would have to check the aws-sdk source code to confirm, but I think it's only populated in cases where the service throws an error and identifies the correct region for you, such as when your request is sent to the wrong region due to misconfiguration -- in which case, this property will tell you the region you *should have* been using.  I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a user policy to allow file uploads, e.g.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:*"],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"]
  }]
}
```